# Energy bounds for pseudoholomorphic curves without symplectic structure

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $(M,J)$ be a compact almost complex manifold and $C>0$ a constant.

[Gromov's compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_compactness_theorem_(topology)) states that the space of $J$-holomorphic curves $u:S^2\to M$ with energy bounded above by $C$ is compact, modulo bubbling. The usual way of employing Gromov's theorem is by using a compatible symplectic form on $(M,J)$ and restricting to the space of $J$-holomorphic maps to a fixed homology class $A\in H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})$: all curves in this class have *equal* energy.

**Question:** Suppose $(M,J)$ has *no compatible symplectic structure*. How can we obtain energy bounds on $J$-holomorphic curves in a fixed homology class $A$?

In particular, suppose $g$ is a $J$-compatible Riemannian metric. Are there any conditions (e.g. curvature bounds) on $g$ which imply a uniform area bound for $J$-holomorphic curves $u:S^2\to M$ in $A$?

The reason I think a condition on $g$ might give uniform energy bounds is that the energy of a $J$-holomorphic curve is equal to the area of the curve with respect to a $J$-compatible metric.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, since for $S^{6}$ the moduli spaces can be non-compact. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219193/pseudo-holomorphic-curves-in-the-six-sphere.